# change selected option of v-select using vue-test-util

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test a component builded with vuetify. For that I'm using vue-test-utils. My goal is to perform a change in the v-select field, and assert hat a mutation is performed. here is my code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-subheader>Standard</v-subheader>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-select
            :items="items"
            v-model="e1"
            label="Select"
            single-line
          ></v-select>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The first test is ok when i set the data:

```
componentWrapper.setData({items: storesList})
expect(componentWrapper.vm.$data.items).toHaveLength(2)
```

I now want to change the selected value I try:

```
componentWrapper.findAll('#option').at(1).setSelected()
```

And also

```
componentWrapper.find('el-select')
```

Can someone help me to retrieve the select and then change the selected value?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Just come update i just found that vuetify create another div and some input for the filter of options. i have chage the behaviour in order to trigger a selection

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have been struggling with this as well and finally found a way to do it. I'm using Jest and vue-test-utils. Basically, you have to do it with two separate steps. Mark the option as selected and then trigger the change on the select.

The HTML part is:

```
      <select id="groupid" v-model="groupID">
        <option value="">-Select group-</option>
        <option v-for="g in groupList" 
          v-bind:value="g.groupId">{{g.groupId}} - {{g.groupName}}
        </option>
      </select>
```

And the test is:

```
it('should populate the subgroup list when a group is selected', () => {
  expect(cmp.vm.groupID).toBe('');
  expect(cmp.findAll('select#groupid > option').length).toBe(3);
  cmp.findAll('select#groupid > option').at(1).element.selected = true;
  cmp.find('select#groupid').trigger('change');
  expect(cmp.vm.groupID).not.toBe('');
});
```

Comment: But `<v-select>` doesn't render default browser <select> markup. Where did you get your `<select>` and `<option>`s from?

Comment: I wasn't using vuetify. Just plain HTML + Vue as shown in my HTML answer above.

Comment: lowered this answer, because qusetion is about Vuetify component V-Select, not simple html select element

Comment: It didn't work for me. I had to use ` click`  instead of `change`.

Comment: This does not answer the question as many testing suites already have methods for interacting with plain HTML <select> elements. What's requested is the equivalent method for Vuetify's <v-select> widget which only uses an <input type=text"> element internally and simulates the drop-down menu with a separate menu widget attached elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: This worked BUT i had to use trigger('input') instead of trigger('change') because I explicitly define my value and input function in my select.

Comment: The OP is clearly using vuetify.  The way vuetify renders a select is the core problem.   This answer should have never been accepted.

Answer (score 11):

Use `wrapper.vm.selectItem('foo')`. It works for me.

I found this in vuetify `v-select` tests:

Old: ~~https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/test/unit/components/VSelect/VSelect.spec.js#L533~~

New: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/b2abe9fa274feeb0c5033bf12cc48276d4ac5a78/packages/vuetify/test/unit/components/VSelect/VSelect.spec.js#L28

Edit: Updated link.

Comment: For newcomers to this issue, here's an updated link since the above has moved:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/b2abe9fa274feeb0c5033bf12cc48276d4ac5a78/packages/vuetify/test/unit/components/VSelect/VSelectList.spec.js

Comment: Excellent answer! It must be marked as correct. This works for me. Thanks @Liang Zhou


```js
const select = wrapper.findComponent({ ref: "myselectref" });
expect(select.exists()).toBeTruthy();
select.vm.selectItem("foo");
expect(wrapper.vm.getMyData()).toStrictEqual("foo");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wrapper.findAll('.v-list__tile__title').at(0).trigger('click')
```

It works for me.
By this code, first option is selected.

Here is [ref](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/6f32c6439a4c789ac992794f5d514db6fec4a5fc/packages/vuetify/test/unit/components/VSelect/VSelect.spec.js#L262).

I used Vuetify v1.5.5.

Answer (score 2):

My solution. It's very equivalent to YounSeon Ahn's response, just the options selector changed. I'm using Vuetify 2.2.11.

```
// Found the v-select
wrapper.find('[data-testid="mySelect"]').trigger('click'); 
// Wait for DOM updating after the click
await localVue.nextTick();
// Find all options and select the first. If you are multiple v-select in your form, the class ".menuable__content__active" represents the current opened menu
wrapper.find('.menuable__content__active').findAll('.v-list-item').at(0).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Just a minor typo in your selector you are missing the I in findAll('.v-list-item')

Comment: I fix it, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

finally got this working for vuetify 1.5. If your v-select looks like this:

```
 <v-select      
        :items="projectManagers"
        :value="selectedProjectManager"
        key="UserId"
        label="Choose Name"
        item-text="FirstName"
        item-value="UserId"        
        id="nameSelect"
        @input="(val)=>{this.handleNameChange(val)}"
 />
```

then do this:

```
wrapper.findAll('#nameSelect').at(0).trigger('input')
```

this works, but for some reason if i do at(1) it does not work. Thankfully for my test case the option at position 0 is fine

Answer (score -1):

This is my final solution to test Vuetify VSelect component in cypressjs:

```
  cy.get('#YourVSelectComponentId', { timeout: 20000 }).should('not.have.attr', 'disabled', 'disabled').click({ force: true }); //find v-select, verify it's visible and then click.

  cy.get('.menuable__content__active').first().find('.v-list__tile').first().should('be.visible').click(); //find opened dropdown, then find first item in options, then click
```

Comment: This question is asking about Vue Test Utils, not Cypress