# vue-test-utils: change event not captured in tests of v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

Am trying to write unit tests for a v-select component using vue-test-utils. I could notice that, change/input event is not getting triggered whenever the item is updated in v-select.

**Component**

```
v-select(
  ref       = "select_cards"
  items     = "[4,8,12]"
  label     = "Number of cards"
  v-model   = "numberOfCards"//data variable
  @change   = "generateRandomValues()"
  :disabled = "isDisabled" //boolean data variable
)
```

Test -

```
const input = wrapper.find("input")
input.element.value = 12
input.trigger("change")
```

I tried with **@input** instead of **@change**. And I tried to set value in test by - wrapper.find("input").setValue(12). But I can notice that change/input event is not getting triggered in unit test. However, this do work when I try it out in browser.

Any suggestions, on how to get the change event on select triggered from unit tests?

P.S - Am using Vue 2.6.11, Vuetify 2.4.9 and Vue test utils 1.1.3

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992183/change-selected-option-of-v-select-using-vue-test-util

Comment: @Kunukn - I tried all the solutions provided in above reference. Its not working yet. Wondering if this is an issue induced in newer versions of vue test utils or am I missing something.

Comment: The Vuetify tests are here https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/__tests__/VSelect.spec.ts   maybe something like this might help?  `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()`